# OData Unbound Function with client side paging

Tags: pagination, odata

I have the following OData function configuration:

```
  ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
  var function = builder
    .Function("GetValues")
    .ReturnsCollection<ObjectType>();
  function.Parameter<int>("parm1");
```

With the following controller action:

```
[ODataRoute("GetValues(parm1={parm1})")]
[RequireOperation(ClientPermissionsEnum.HSA)]
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = ODataConfig.AllowedOptions)]
public IQueryable<ObjectType> GetValues(int parm1)
{
  return _repository.GetValues(parm1).AsQueryable());
}
```

The ODataConfig.AllowedOptions includes: skip, orderby, count, top, format and filter.

When I go to the http://..../GetValues(1)?%24format=json&%24top=5&%24count=true url, I get "@odata.context" and "value" properties of the response.  The "value" property correctly includes only the first 5 results.  I can issue another request with the proper skip values and get the next 5 and so on.  However, the responses never include an "@odata.count" property.  This prevents the client from being aware that there are more results than can fit on a single page.

**Is it possible to configure an unbound function to include the count in the response for client side paging?**  This works fine for entity bound odata routes, but I would prefer to not have to do that as the parm1 value is not currently a property of the ObjectType class.

Answer (score 0):

what version are you using, this is fixed in https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/484, I think you can upgrade your OData Web API to 5.9.1 or breaking change release 6.0.0 and try again. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData